# Python Positioning correctly in a while loop

Tags: python

My current code works but when the option menu appears, and i select an option, its supposed to repeat from the selection again, however my code restarts from the start where it asks to enter a number rather than entering an option.

```
n = 0
amount = 0
total = 0

while n != "":
    try:
        n=int(input("Enter a number: "))
        amount = amount+1
        total = total + n
    except ValueError:
        average = total/amount


        print()
        print("Which option would you like?")
        print("1 - Number of values entered")
        print("2 - Total of the values entered")
        print("3 - Average of values entered")
        print("0 - Exit")

        choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
        if choice == 1:
            print(amount, "numbers were input.")


        elif choice == 2:
            print("The total of the sequence is", total)

        elif choice == 3:
            print("The average is",average)

        elif choice == 0:
            print("Exit")
            break
```

So it means that I need to reposition my code within the while loop, or take the input stage to a different position?

Comment: `n != ""` doesn't look right to me. `n` is always an integer. and no integer will ever be equal to the empty string.

Comment: I solved that problem with the "except ValueError" part. My code runs and all, it just repeats from the wrong section

Answer (score 1):

You need a nested loop

(tried to change your original code as little as possible) I changed it to include your options menu within a while loop (in addition to another break statement outside the while loop, to make sure the program doesn't repeat itself (unless you want it to...)).

```
n = 0
amount = 0
total = 0

while n != "":
    try:
        n=int(input("Enter a number: "))
        amount = amount+1
        total = total + n
    except ValueError:
        average = total/amount

        choice = -1         # new
        while(choice != 0): # new
            print()
            print("Which option would you like?")
            print("1 - Number of values entered")
            print("2 - Total of the values entered")
            print("3 - Average of values entered")
            print("0 - Exit")

            choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
            if choice == 1:
                print(amount, "numbers were input.")


            elif choice == 2:
                print("The total of the sequence is", total)

            elif choice == 3:
                print("The average is",average)

            elif choice == 0:
                print("Exit")
                break
        break # new
```

keep in mind this COULD be a good deal more robust, and there exists no functionality for handling options selected outside the ones specified (though should someone enter a 5 or something it will just repeat)

Comment: Oh I see, Thank you; I ran through it and it makes sense. Its amazing how simple things can be but experience I guess is the key. Also I noticed u put a semi colon at the end of the break, i removed that because I believe that's used in java

Comment: Oh god you're right; I constantly switch between C++ and Python so I can't seem to drop that dirty habit. fixed

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I find it cleaner to have your cope loop forever with `while True` and to break out of it as necessary. I also try to reduce nesting where possible, and I don't like to use exception handling for a valid input choice. Here's a slightly reworked example:

amount = 0
total = 0

```
while True:
    n = input("Enter a number: ")
    if n == "":
        break
    amount = amount+1
    total = total + int(n)

average = total/amount

while True:    
    print()
    print("Which option would you like?")
    print("1 - Number of values entered")
    print("2 - Total of the values entered")
    print("3 - Average of values entered")
    print("0 - Exit")

    choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    if choice == 1:
        print(amount, "numbers were input.")

    elif choice == 2:
        print("The total of the sequence is", total)

    elif choice == 3:
        print("The average is",average)

    elif choice == 0:
        print("Exit")
        break
```